# Как программно отправить символ в текстовый редактор

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Я делаю транслит. Используя windows hook, я беру буквы, которые печатаю. Теперь как отправить транслированную букву в открытый Word или другой текстовый редактор?

Comment: Пожалуйста, раскройте Ваш вопрос более подробно.

Comment: @ixSci   полученную букву через windows hook отправить в курсор

Comment: Я исправил Ваш заголовок, то, как Вы получаете scan code не существенно. Судя по Вашей задаче Вам нужно найти способ подачи этого scan code  в соответствующее приложение. Учитесь формулировать свои вопросы яснее, так у Вас куда больше шансов получить ответ.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Могу предложить несколько способов.

1. Punto Switcher работает через <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. То есть, если он решает исправить текст, то он отправляет активному окну соответствующее количество <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, меняет раскладку, затем снова "проигрывает" события нажатия на клавиши.

   У разных приложений есть разные "особенности" получения состояния клавиатуры, поэтому, если изберёте такой метод, готовьтесь к мукам с каждым частным случаем.

   Другим недостатком этого способа является зависимость от последовательного набора символов. Если во время ввода текста нажимать стрелки или любые клавиши, которые меняют положение в тексте, то вернуться назад будет практически невозможно.
2. Вы можете создать свою раскладку клавиатуры. Одной клавише вы можете назначить только один символ, но можно добавлять аккорды с <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (правый <kbd>Alt</kbd> как <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) и вытворять прочие интересные штуки.
3. Самый простой и надёжный способ — это полагаться на буфер обмена. Пусть юзер выберет текст в приложении, который нужно преобразовать, нажмёт какое-то сочетание клавиш, ваше приложение отправит <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, преобразует текст, отправит <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

   Этот способ будет работать почти везде (везде, где нормально поддерживается буфер обмена), не будет зависеть от способа редактирования текста, и юзер будет полностью контролировать процесс.

   Punto Switcher поддерживает и этот способ, к слову.